SQL Oracle/Concat and then use it in select * from
I want to define a variable for further use in the query.
Something like this:
--does not work--
define Name = 'Table_name'

define tableNm1 = concat(&Name, '_001')
define tableNm2 = concat(&Name, , '_002')

select * from &tableNm2


This is the same question you asked before. The solution is called "Dynamic SQL".

@TheImpaler - to be fair to STEP it's exactly that question, not a repeat; looking at the timeline it's graduated from the staging ground, and comments there don't transfer.


& is used for substitution variables and these are evaluated by the client application (i.e. SQL*Plus, SQL Developer or SQLCL) and not by the database.
You cannot set an identifier (for a table or column) using string concatenation in a static SQL query so using concat (or the || operator) is never going to work. If you wanted to do it in SQL or PL/SQL on the database then you would need to use dynamic SQL, SQL macros, polymorphic functions, or something similar.

However, you can do what you want with just substitution variables.
From the Using Substitution Variables  documentation:

If you wish to append characters immediately after a substitution variable, use a period to separate the variable from the character. For example:
SELECT SALARY FROM EMP_DETAILS_VIEW WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID='&X.5';
Enter value for X:  20

is interpreted as
SELECT SALARY FROM EMP_DETAILS_VIEW WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID='205';


So use:
DEFINE Name = Table_name

SELECT * FROM &Name._002;

(Note: The table name is an identifier and not a string literal so it does not need to have single quotes.)
Which will be interpreted as:
SELECT * FROM Table_name_002;


You can't use concat as part of the table name within the SQL statement, and what you are doing now is going to try to do that (poorly, but it wouldn't work anyway).
If you want to use a common root for your two final substitution variables then don't try to use the SQL concat function, just build your later defines referring to the first one:
define Name = 'Table_name'

define tableNm1 = '&Name._001'
define tableNm2 = '&Name._002'

(The period in &Name._001 is important; if you just did &Name_001 then the whole of Name_001 would be seen as a separate new variable which hasn't yet been defined, and you'd be prompted for a value for that. And none of those need the single quotes as there are (now) no spaces, and they're going to be used as unquoted identifiers later anyway; but they aren't going to break it.)
Then
select * from &tableNm2
/

will be substituted as
select * from Table_name_002
/

